# Css variables and browser read

Tags: css

I have a question:

Are CSS variables the most optimized way to write code for the browser?

What is easier for browser, to read multiple definitions like this:

```
.a { color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }
.b { color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }
.c { color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }
.d { color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }
```

Or to read variables:

```
:root { --c1: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }

.a { color: var(--c1); }
.b { color: var(--c1); }
.c { color: var(--c1); }
.d { color: var(--c1); }
```

And I mean not about bytes saving or readable format,  just what is faster, easier, and more useful for browser work.

Comment: the first one since you will directly read the value of color. In the second example you need to first evalute the CSS variable then read the color value

Comment: Thanks!
I thought so.

Let's look at another situation:
What if we set in variable base64 data/image code. 
And after it will be used in 10 places as background-image. 
For bytes saving this will be more better variant, because if image code has 1000 symbols, then write it just 1 time as variable better then 10*1000
And I think, what if browser when first time read definition of variable some how take in mind that this variable is this image,  and in future when he find this variable, just put image for it and don't read every 10 times all symbols from variable.

How you think?

Comment: no, CSS variables aren't *find and replace*. The browser need to individually evalute each variable in order to find the value. So it's easy for you to write it once this is clear BUT the browser will do 1000 evaluations and I am pretty sure that a variable evalution is more expensive then a simple value. check this for more details : https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/#using-variables it explains what the browser do when it find a `var()`. Let's don't forget that a CSS variable is inherited so if you define it inside root ALL the element will get it (potential memory issue)